# Can I Modify the Output of SP2013 Field Values in Snippets or Page Layout?

Tags: column, page-layout, snippet

I would like to know if there is a way to modify the output of page fields in SharePoint 2013 from within a snippet or within the page layout.

- I have a field of type Hyperlink or Picture.
- I want to simply get only the URL with no formatting.
- I cannot do this client-side.  It is to populate an OG:image meta tag and as such it must be included in the HTML response.
- I want to do it in the page layout for one particular type of page on my site and not site-wide.

From the snippet editor I see a bunch of template fields, but no idea how to supply the templates.

I did find the control template but that appeared to only be for the edit mode of the control.

I tried adding my hyperlink or picture column directly to the page layout using the code below:

```
<!--MS:<PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue FieldName="Thumbnail" runat="server">-->
```

This produces the following output:

```
<a href="http://[my site url]/public/news/PublishingImages/bills-1.jpg">The Energy Information Administration is forecasting a slight rise in electricity prices in 2017.</a>
```

What I would like to get as output is:

```
http://[my site url]/public/news/PublishingImages/bills-1.jpg
```

How do I affect the READ mode of the output or specify only the URL portion of my Thumbnail column?

Alternatively, can I somehow format the data within the page layout if I don't have code-behind?

I'm stumped as to how to do this.